# Unable to find csv file on ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment

Anyone who knows how to solve this error please help me. Below is my code for reading the csv file. When I tried to upload it showed me **Server Error in '/' Application. Could not find file 'C:/...csv ** Im a beginner in c#.

**ReadCSV**

```
    string filename = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;

    using (CsvFileReader reader = new CsvFileReader(filename))
    {
        CsvRow row = new CsvRow();
        while (reader.ReadRow(row))
        {
            foreach (string s in row)
            {
                Console.Write(s);
                Console.Write(" ");
                TextBox1.Text += s;
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

**CSVClass**

```
  public class CsvFileReader : StreamReader
    {
        public CsvFileReader(Stream stream)
            : base(stream)
        {
        }

        public CsvFileReader(string filename): base(filename)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Reads a row of data from a CSV file
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="row"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool ReadRow(CsvRow row)
        {
            row.LineText = ReadLine();
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.LineText))
                return false;

            int pos = 0;
            int rows = 0;

            while (pos < row.LineText.Length)
            {
                string value;

                // Special handling for quoted field
                if (row.LineText[pos] == '"')
                {
                    // Skip initial quote
                    pos++;

                    // Parse quoted value
                    int start = pos;
                    while (pos < row.LineText.Length)
                    {
                        // Test for quote character
                        if (row.LineText[pos] == '"')
                        {
                            // Found one
                            pos++;

                            // If two quotes together, keep one
                            // Otherwise, indicates end of value
                            if (pos >= row.LineText.Length || row.LineText[pos] != '"')
                            {
                                pos--;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        pos++;
                    }
                    value = row.LineText.Substring(start, pos - start);
                    value = value.Replace("\"\"", "\"");
                }
                else
                {
                    // Parse unquoted value
                    int start = pos;
                    while (pos < row.LineText.Length && row.LineText[pos] != ',')
                        pos++;
                    value = row.LineText.Substring(start, pos - start);
                }

                // Add field to list
                if (rows < row.Count)
                    row[rows] = value;
                else
                    row.Add(value);
                rows++;

                // Eat up to and including next comma
                while (pos < row.LineText.Length && row.LineText[pos] != ',')
                    pos++;
                if (pos < row.LineText.Length)
                    pos++;
            }
            // Delete any unused items
            while (row.Count > rows)
                row.RemoveAt(rows);

            // Return true if any columns read
            return (row.Count > 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Cloud it has been uploaded but the used property only contains the client-side name of the file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName` is the filename from your client/browser - it does not contain a path...

You either use [`FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.inputstream.aspx) to access it

```
using (CsvFileReader reader = new CsvFileReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream))
```

OR you first save it to disk (anywhere you have needed permissions) via [`FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.saveas.aspx) and then access that file.

Comment: wow ure great!! FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream works..thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the file that is being uploaded to disk first. Something like this:

```
string fileSavePath= Sever.MapPath("/files/" + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
FileUpload1.SaveAs(fileSavePath);

using (CsvFileReader reader = new CsvFileReader(fileSavePath))
....
```

Haven't tested this code, but should give you a starting point.